# forcing a user to chose at least one element in a form before advancing (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a situation where I have this form, and am trying to force a user to chose at least one element within this form before they can advance.  I am working on a rails app that I did not build, and so there is a possibility that I am not looking at enough of the information. (note, I did break this up for readability purposes, in reality it is 4 lines of code)

```
control-group
  = f.label :clinic_ids, "Clinics", class: 'control-label'
  .controls
    = f.select :clinic_ids, Clinic.accessible_by(current_ability, :manage).collect
 { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, {}, :class => 'chzn-select',
 :'data-placeholder' => 'You must select a clinic before advancing', 
 :multiple => true, :required => true
```

Now I was under the assumption that the     ":required => true" would be the solution to this issue, however that is not working.

So looking further into the code, I am noticing that there is nothing in the controller with defining any scope with the clinic_id's

So I suppose my question would be, is there a simple solution to solving this issue? Or do I need to create something within the controller that would make this happen. If I needed to create something in the controller, what would I have to do?

Comment: The `required` attribute seems to not play nice in all browsers. Using jQuery, you could disable submissions until a selection has been chosen...